# Android Studio can't find kotlinx module generated from layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm using the standard Kotlin Android extensions to refer to `View`s defined in a layout XML using the typed IDs in `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main`. I am able to compile my project both from Android Studio and from the CLI, so these references seem to be resolved correctly; however, in  Android Studio the import statement is shown as unresolved, and so none of the typed IDs work.

My `build.gradle` is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "0.3.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.8.3"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    expectedBy project(':engine')
    implementation project(':dialogue')
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.daniel-stoneuk:material-about-library:2.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around this by making a separate Android library module with just the platform-specific bits (and, importantly, no `kotlinx` usage), and then importing that into the main app module. This means the main app module no longer needs to use `kotlin-platform-android` and can just be `kotlin-android` instead.

So in summary, in the module containing the platform-specific bits:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    expectedBy project(':engine')
}
```

and in the main module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xmulti-platform"]
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation project(':engine-android')
}
```

Note that we still need to pass `-Xmulti-platform` to the Kotlin compiler to be able to link to `:engine-android`; but we're using the vanilla `kotlin-android` plugin which seems to work OK with `kotlin-android-extensions`.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code, into the apply plugin from build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```